# How do i allow MediaWiki spamming & vandalism

Tags: spam, spamming, spam-bots

After stopping spam & vandalism on my Mediawiki website how do I allow spam and vandalism on my MediaWiki website?

Comment: Why would you want spam and vandalism?

Comment: In order for for me to help those who are combating spam and vandalism on their MediaWiki websites I must have it happening to my MediaWiki website.

Comment: "After stopping spam & vandalism..." - How did you stop it in the first place? Can you "undo" it?

Comment: I undid every step I used to combat my MediaWiki spam and vandalism. The spam bots never came back. I really would like for other MediaWiki websites to redirect their spam bots to my website to let the edit.